# Oracle BPM and Oracle ADF

Tags: business-process-management, oracle-adf

We're developing a BPM application to be run on Weblogic, and all the tutorials point to using Oracle ADF for rendering the task forms. My question is: is it feasible to use some other framework other than Oracle ADF for this? We're not really that familiar with either Oracle BPM or Oracle ADF, but we can't avoid using Oracle BPM (contract reqt), so we would like to see if we can avoid Oracle ADF instead to minimize the learning effort.

Answer (score 5):

At first we consumed Oracle **ADF 12c** for generating Human tasks.
It was so easy to create Human tasks with BPM suite's wizards but It was semi difficult:

- it was not easy to change payloads and forms after create.
- debugging was so hard
- deployment was not as fast as what we need.
- etc

Finally we decided to use angular 4+  for generating human tasks with Oracle BPM API. That was very nice experience and finally we decided to made a custom workspace by angular.

Comment: deployment took us much time

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, and in fact there is a great application using Struts to create your own BPM Client.

Find the link in here:
http://redstack.wordpress.com/2011/03/09/worklist-overview/
Another link to use .NET app as your worklist app in here:
http://redstack.wordpress.com/2012/02/10/writing-a-human-task-ui-in-net-casp-net-or-in-fact-anything-other-than-adf/

Answer (score 2):

If you can't avoid using Oracle BPM then you should use ADF, especially because as you say you are not very familiar with Oracle BPM neither. ADF is the only option given by Oracle and therefore the only with the Oracle support for BPM integration.

I'm pretty sure that could be another alternatives but you will lost a lot of integration advantages, and taking a big risk, and generally choosing Oracle BPM is for people who do not want to take risks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on Oracle BPM, but have built dozens of BPM solutions using other platforms both commercial and open source.
If Oracle BPM exposes a Rest API (as ALL decent BPM systems do these days) then you are free to create your UI in whatever technology you choose.

By separating the UI from the business logic (i.e. BPM) layer using a consistent interface layer such as the Rest API, you will be able to take advantage of UI skills you may already possess in house.

Let me know if you need any specific assistance.

Regards,
Greg

Answer (score 1):

By Default, the human task forms get created in ADF, so it makes it easier to handle the payload and manipulate or implement your business logic over there, if you are using Oracle BPM, Oracle ADF will be your best option as it integrates well with BPM.